# checking ifeq for variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

Following is not working, do you know why?

Note: CURRENT_CLUSTER is not 'my-local-cluster' and stil fails.

```
check-env:
    ifeq ($(CURRENT_CLUSTER), 'my-local-cluster')
        $(error CURRENT_CLUSTER is local $(CURRENT_CLUSTER), should be production cluster)
    endif
```

Comment: There are many errors here. First, `makefile` will compare everything on both part of the `,` in the `if(n)eq`, meaning that `ifeq (s, s)` will fail because of the space, such as `ifeq (s,'s')` because of `'`. Also, `$(error ...)` is supposed to appear outside of the recipe. It stops the compilation before the target is called

Comment: @Zelnes: `$(error ...)` can perfectly be used in the recipe, for instance to force it to fail in unsupported situations.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Wouldn't it fail before the recipe is reached ?

Comment: @Zelnes: no, it is part of the recipe. It will be expanded (and fail) only when make expands the recipe, just before passing it to the shell, and only if the conditional passes.

Comment: The problem is you can't use `ifeq` etc. which are _make_ constructs, inside a recipe which is passed to the shell for parsing.  By "inside a recipe" I mean, indented with a TAB character so that it is part of the recipe commands.  You could put it "in a recipe" but not indented with TAB, but it'll be parsed when the makefile is parsed not when the recipe is invoked.  If you want a test to happen inside the recipe, you have to use shell constructs like `if ...; then ... fi` etc.

Comment: @MadScientist: I just tested with GNU Make 4.2.1. If the conditional is **not** indented but the `$(error ...)` is, make fails if and only if `CURRENT_CLUSTER=my-local-cluster` **and** `check-env` is invoked. I also tested with an `else` and it worked as expected. And if another goal is invoked, make does not fail, even if the conditional passes. Is there something I missed here?

Comment: In the example above the `ifeq` is indented.  That's what I was referring to.  If you don't indent `ifeq` it will be evaluated when the makefile is read.  As long as the condition is static (doesn't rely on the specific recipe or order in which the makefile is read) then it will work.  But if `CURRENT_CLUSTER` is a target-specific variable, or depends itself on automatic variables like `$@` or `$*`, or is reset to a different value after this rule is defined, then it won't work.

Comment: @MadScientist: agreed.

Comment: It must be left justified, no tabulation.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you want would be something like :

```
check-env:
ifeq ($(CURRENT_CLUSTER),my-local-cluster)
    $(error CURRENT_CLUSTER is local $(CURRENT_CLUSTER), should be production cluster)
endif
    @echo Whatever

all:
    @echo "Still good"
```

This will produce this result :

```
$ make check-env CURRENT_CLUSTER=my-local-cluster
Makefile:220: *** CURRENT_CLUSTER is local my-local-cluster, should be
$ make all CURRENT_CLUSTER=my-local-cluster
Still good
$ make check-env CURRENT_CLUSTER=anything
Whatever
```

Comment: Note: as @MadScientist noted, this works only if the condition is static. It may be important to keep this in mind.